# How to better debug a Javascript error on Chrome / iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, google-chrome, inertiajs

I am using Inertia.js to build a Vue.js application, and I encountered a Javascript error which only occurs in Chrome app on iOS, it doesn't happen on Chrome app on Android, or Safari app on iOS, it doesn't happen on desktop browsers too.

Because Chrome app on iOS is built with WKWebView, which looks like a reskin of Safari app, I didn't find a way to remote debug with it. The only option I found is opening a `chrome://inspect` tab on the phone, however, it only prints `ERROR: object [Object]` which is not helpful.

I am wondering if there is other ways to debug with Chrome on iOS.